# Is there a way to return multiple variables from a function in C?

Tags: c, function, variables

I am currently coming back to C after a long spell with Python. I was wondering if there was a way to return information on more than one variable in C. The best method I could think of was returning a structure which contained the variables. Is this the best way?

Comment: yep, right. Otherwise, pass pointers.

Comment: You could use `vectors`

Comment: Python data structures (i.e, lists) don't have a one-to-one correspondence to C++ data structures (queues, stacks, vectors). You have to be more specific about what you're trying to do.

Comment: There is no 'best' way. You already mentioned a solution, use it.

Answer (score 4):

C doesn't support tuples or similar features that would allow you to do this. So, the answer is unfortunately **no**.

As you said, the closest you can get is by defining your own custom `struct` which can then be used to store the values you want to return.

Comment: @sjsam true, but as c is a subset of c++, if c++ doesn't support it, c won't either.

Comment: @weston : I agree, but I would consider them separate languages here for `tags` sake :D

Answer (score 2):

When multiple variables are related to each other in some obvious way, such as two variables `(x, y)` describing a coordinate, a `(firstName, lastName, address)` contact definition, et cetera, the solution returning a `struct` is a good logical choice.

In situations when you must return multiple variables unrelated to each other a better approach is to pass pointers for the result, or pick one value as the "main answer" and pass pointers for other values.

[`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) function from the standard library is an example  of the "hybrid" approach: it *returns* the parsed value, and *sets* the end pointer through a pointe-to-pointer passed to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can indirectly do so by using pointers as parameters. `myDivide` indirectly returns the result of division and modulo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void myDivide(int x, int y, int* div, int* mod);

int main(void) {
    int x = 100;
    int y = 42;
    int div, mod;

    myDivide(x, y, &div, &mod);
    printf("%d / %d = %d\n", x, y, div);
    printf("%d %% %d = %d\n", x, y, mod);

    return (0);
}

void myDivide(int x, int y, int* div, int* mod) {
    *div = x/y;
    *mod = x%y;
}
```